# How to get end to end performance analysis tomcat

Tags: java, performance, spring, memory, tomcat6

I have a web app that performs great and then suddenly a page request will freeze up and time out and then everything will be dandy again for a little bit and the same thing happens.

I'm having hard time getting to the bottom of this because there are so many variables that can be analyzed.

Is there any way: a tool or step plan that can help me get to the bottom of this and basically analyze this whole thing from page request to database call and identify the potential problems? I use New Relic and MAT and I just started using Javamelody but to be honest: where to focus? And usually when a page freezes / times out it's not clear where the bottleneck was. What are thresholds / red flags to look out for?

Kind regards,
Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the server side, I found that [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) is usually a much better tool than profilers. Mostly because it's quick, command line and already installed with your server's JDK.

A typical cause for an intermittent web app slow down is a thread waiting on some lock to release.

Run `jstack` when the web app appears stuck and look through the threads to see which ones are stuck on a lock and what the lock is. Here's a quick [tutorial](http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/jstack-Detect-Java-Thread-Deadlocks.html) because it can sound daunting at first but it's really simple.

Comment: Along with jstack, I'd add jstat to the toolbox, as an intermitent pause sounds like a stop-the-world GC pause. If the freeze happens at the same time the GC count increases, it's likely to be the GC. You can then activate the verbose GC logs to get more details.

Comment: Thanks for those tips. Reviewing my jstack output. I see somethings that are a little puzzling to me:
I see a number of http threads that are waiting for the c3p0 resourcepool to become available
I see 3 c3p0 ThreadPoolAsyncRunners available (when my config defined a minimum pool size of 10 and a max pool size of 100. All 3 are "locked" 
- locked <0x000000009d5cd688> (a com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream)

So I guess there's my answer. It seems the c3p0 pool size is not set correctly. Now to find out why and how to solve it.

Comment: It could also be that your MySQL database has a restrictive configuration that allows only a small numbers of connections (or is shared with another app that sucks it all)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tips here and elsewhere I found a few things that seems to have affected things although we'll have to see how it works out in the long term. Now, it seems to be better although it's hard to point my finger to exactly what made the biggest difference. Things I did:
* Made Spring datasource lazy so that requests that can be served from the cache don't create a needless transaction
* Changed mySQL thread_cache_size to 50. It was 8 before.
* Changed from c3p0 to BoneCP

For now, it looks like the intermittent pauses don't occur anymore.